# How to detect when user click Uber Button (UBSDKRideRequestButton)

Tags: uber-api

Is there anyway to detect if user clicks the uber button ?

```
// initialize uber request button
if (!_rideRequestButton) {
    _rideRequestButton = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] initWithClient:self.ridesClient];
    _rideRequestButton.delegate = self;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I can add a target action to the button

```
 [_rideRequestButton addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(rideRequestButtonIsTapped:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)rideRequestButtonIsTapped:(UBSDKRideRequestButton *)button
```

This approach is also recommend by uber:

https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for when the user requests a ride using the button by using callbacks:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/button/ios#handle-callbacks-for-rides

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the call back is for loading ride information but not for user "clicking" event.